# Post to Top in Array

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom field with a value of 1 and 0, I would like in an array of a post type those posts with value 1 to be in the type and the others below them. It is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You sure can, just order them by the `meta_field`, like in this example

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'post_type', //The slug of your post type
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'meta_key', // The name of your field
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC' // Will put the higher values first
));
```

Learn more in the [Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Comment: as it is the answer will not work because 1. `wp_query` is not a function and 2. the codex was deprecated years ago. you should not count on the information in it to be accurate any longer

Comment: I've updated my answer, thanks for pointing out about the WP_Query, I had forgotten the `new` and about the Codex, he maybe depracated, but it's still valid for most of the things in Wordpress, but to avoid any further problems, I changed the link to the `Developer Wordpress` site.

Comment: upvoted, but it should really be `get_posts` :)

Comment: This will work for both, since `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` internally, but since in his question, it's `get_posts` I edited my answer